# Excel 2007: help with a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to implement the following function/formula in Excel 2007 which would give me the following:

for x<0.68 y=0
for 0.68<=x<0.81 y=1
for 0.81<=x<1 y=2
for 1<=x<1.25 y=3
for x>1.25 y=4

Please advise.

Comment: what are the x and y cell values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1 - Make a very long string of nested IF statements.

2 - Use a lookup table.  The lookup table is the best bet IMO.  Check out directions [HERE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-lookup-functions-HA010287334.aspx).